# Scrollview show as default size or custom design of scrollview in xaml, uwp

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, xamarin.uwp

In my Scrollview, Its width is thin by default, When hovering it, its width becomes normal.
But I want a customorized scrollview with a fixed width in xamarin or always default scroll
Both vertical and horizontal scroll
Any Suggestion Please

What I have tried:

```
<ScrollView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                                        <StackLayout
                                            Padding="0,0,0,0"
                                            BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource BrandComplementBackgroundColor}"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                            Orientation="Vertical"
                                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                            Parent="">
                                            <FlexLayout
                                                BackgroundColor="Red"
                                                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ChipSetCollection}"
                                                Direction="Column"
                                                JustifyContent="Start">
                                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <views:ChipSetItemTemplate />
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                            </FlexLayout>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ScrollView>
```

This is what I'm getting
[image]

On hovering only getting this default scroll bar
but without hovering I want default scroll bar
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> But I want a customorized scrollview with a fixed width

For your requirement, you need to custom `ScrollBar` style and disable `ExpandedAnimation` and  update `VerticalThumb` ScaleX from 0.125 to 0.5. I have made part style below, please find it from generic.xaml file, change it like following then paste into UWP client App xaml resource.

Copy the complete  `ScrollBar` style and  find `ConsciousStates`  `VisualStateGroup` and delete it that could disable `ScrollBar` expanded when point over.

```
<x:Double x:Key="SmallScrollThumbScale">0.5</x:Double>

<Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarSize}" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarSize}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarBackground}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarForeground}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                 <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollBar">
                        <Grid x:Name="Root">
......
```

Comment: this way does not work.. it is possible to show always default scroll bar in scrollview

Comment: Yes , it always show the scroll bar in the scroll view, but it has update the default scrollbar's width.

Comment: scroll view behavior: it always shows as a slim scroll while hovering the scroll bar width expand right?

what i want:
using scrollview  scroll should display always 
or
want to change the slim scroll width

you're above code for scrollbar not scrollview
so that's not working for me

Comment: Yep, above code only effect for scrollbar.  and do you mean the scrollview width will be changed when mouse hover?

Comment: yes nico,
im asking for scrollview  it is possible?

Comment: but I can't reproduce your problem that scrollview width will be changed when mouse hover

Comment: here i attached  2 image
1st one-- without mouse hover
2nd ---- with mouse hover

Comment: could mind share us with [mcve]